# Special characters for dynamic objects?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, expandoobject

Is there any limitations on the kind of characters that I can use to create a property for a dynamic object?

Is there a list of characters that I cannot use (e.g. / * @)?

Comment: Why don't you just try using those characters to see for yourself...If you really want a conclusive answer you can always read the C# specs to see what a legal identifier can be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you have:

```
dynamic eo = new ExpandoObject();
```

then clearly if you expand the object through C# syntax, you need to follow the C# rules, for example:

```
eo.ValidCSharpIdentifier = 42;
eo._OK = 42;
eo.æ = 42;
```

But if you expand `eo` by casting to `IDictionary<,>`, then you can use other characters:

```
((IDictionary<string, object>)eo).Add("NotValidC#Identifier", 42);
((IDictionary<string, object>)eo).Add("42", 42);
((IDictionary<string, object>)eo).Add("/", 42);
((IDictionary<string, object>)eo).Add("*", 42);
((IDictionary<string, object>)eo).Add("@", 42);
((IDictionary<string, object>)eo).Add("", 42);
```

As we see, strange identifiers are possible. The string must be an object though, so a `null` reference cannot be used (as in `.Add(null, 42) /* illegal */`).

There *seems* to be no restriction on the name used. The string keys *seem* to be compared with an *ordinal* string comparison, like in `EqualityComparer<string>.Default` or `StringComparer.Ordinal`.

Certainly, some .NET languages have different rules for valid characters in names, compared to the C# rules.

Comment: Thanks, however I noticed that when binding a List<dynamic> with that kind of identifiers to a radgridview, the columns would show as empty columns, I guess the bug is related to telerik in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Any Unicode Standard Annex 15 character (and an underscore), as the [C# spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx) says:

> The rules for identifiers given in this section correspond exactly to those recommended by the Unicode Standard Annex 15, except that underscore is allowed as an initial character (as is traditional in the C programming language), Unicode escape sequences are permitted in identifiers, and the "@" character is allowed as a prefix to enable keywords to be used as identifiers.

For a list of characters that need prefix with `@`, take a look [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).